# Running gulp task on shared hosting Apache

Tags: node.js, cron, gulp

Is it possible to run gulp task as crone job on Apache server i have gulp.js and some tasks like this

```
gulp.task('image-compress', function() {
        gulp.src('./img/**/*{css,png,jpg,gif}')
            .pipe(imagemin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./img'));
    }
);
```

The problem is that i can start it on my machine, but user will add a lot of more pictures on CMS, and i need to optimize those pictures, lets say once a day?

The question is not about this task, it is how to start gulp on production shared hosting server, that i can not access command line :(

Comment: Do you have gulp installed on the host? It is a dev tool after all.

Comment: yes i have it installed

Comment: That's great. Not sure how you confirm it without shell access tho. Anyway, if you have it installed there, you need to upload your tasks to the server, and set up the cron task via control panel.

Comment: Can you post me and answer to see how?

Comment: How what? You can run the script locally, so you know the command. How to set up a cron job depends on the control panel. For CPanel it is https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs, for others it is different, and may not be possible at all.